# Pandas choose from column with value and get column name

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'choice': [None, None, None], 
                       'Active': [0, 0, 1], 
                       'Completed': [1, 0, 0], 
                       'Cancelled': [0, 1, 0]})
```

I want to have a result:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'choice': ['Completed', 'Cancelled', 'Active']})
```

I want to get column name depending which on them has the 1.

Comment: use `m=sample.drop('choice',1)` and then `m.dot(m.columns)` or `sample.iloc[:,1:].idxmax(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
data = pd.melt(sample,value_vars=['Active','Completed','Cancelled'],var_name='choice')
data= data[data['value']==1].drop(['value'],axis=1)
print(data)
```

```
      choice
2     Active
3  Completed
7  Cancelled
```